# Where does Oracle Enterprise Manager derive the "User Logon Time" metrics from?

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

Oracle's enterprise manager has a metric named "User Logon Time" and will show an alert if that exceeds a certain threshold.

I would like to retrieve the numbers stored for this metrics directly using a SQL query.

However, I cannot find any view where this is stored. I can find "Logons Per Sec", "Logons Per Txn", "Current Logons Count" in the `DBA_HIST_SYSMETRIC_SUMMARY` view and "logons cumulative" and "logons current" in the `DBA_HIST_SYSSTAT`  view.

The view `DBA_HIST_METRIC_NAME` also doesn't list any metric of that name.

So where does the Enterprise Manager get that information from?

I'm talking about this alert:

[image]

Comment: I believe this is measured by the EMAgent. It measures the time difference between attempting to log on to the database and getting the "connected" message. I'm not sure where this data is stored.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11857_01/em.111/e16285/oracle_database.htm#EMDBM2050 would be handy.

Comment: @Raj: but that doesn't explain where it is stored and in which system view this is available.

Comment: "Logon Per Sec" and "Logon Per Tx" can be found in OEM REPOSITORY (e.g. look in sysman.mgmt$metrics_daily view, the metric_name = 'instance_throughput' and metric_column like 'logons%'). The other metric will also be there, these are maintained in OEM REPO not in individual targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Logon Per Sec" and "Logon Per Tx" can be found in OEM REPOSITORY (e.g. look in sysman.mgmt$metrics_daily view, the metric_name = 'instance_throughput' and metric_column like 'logons%'). The other metric will also be there, these are maintained in OEM REPO not in individual targets.

Comment: The information I was looking for was available using `select * from sysman.mgmt$metric_daily where metric_name = 'Response'
 and metric_column = 'userLogon'`

Answer (score -1):

You can get it directly from DB target without having OEM rep.

```
select * from DBA_HIST_SYSMETRIC_HISTORY 
where metric_name = 'Logons Per Sec'
```

Comment: Please read my question: I have stated that I can fined `Logons Per Sec` in DBA_HIST_SYSMETRIC_HISTORY. But I am looking for `User Logon Time`

Answer (score -1):

in the dba_hist_sys_time_model, there is a stat_name for 'connection management call elapsed time'. You can check that.